# Magento 2 : admin form image file validation not working in server

Tags: jquery, magento2.2.2, validation, file-upload

In my form i am using this code to upload the file.

```
$fieldset->addField( 
        'banner_image', 
        'image', 
        [ 
        'name' => 'banner_image', 
        'label' => __('Banner Image'), 
        'title' => __('Banner Image'), 
        'note' => __('Allowed File Types : (JPG,JPEG,PNG).'), 
        'path'=> $model->getImagePath(), 
        'required' => true, 
        'value' => $model->getImagePath() 
        ] 
        )->setAfterElementHtml(' 
        <script> 
        require([ 
        "jquery", 
        ], function($){ 
        $(document).ready(function () { 
        if($("#page_banner_image").attr("value")){ 
        $("#page_banner_image").removeClass("required-file"); 
        }else{ 
        $("#page_banner_image").addClass("required-file"); 
        } 
        $( "#page_banner_image" ).attr( "accept", "image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png" ); 
        }); 
        }); 
        </script> 
        ');
```

In the edit form `$("#page_banner_image").attr("value")` its is not working in the server not in localhost.Its always return empty value even if i have value for the image field.

I tried `.val()` method too.Its also not working correctly

Comment: I am having the same issue. It is working in local. but not in server.And this issue is specific to chrome.  Any solution for this?

Comment: sorry i couldn't find a solution, and removed this validation in my code.